# How to make this extension method compile?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods

I am trying to create an extension method for the generic delegate `Action<T>` to be able to make simple asynchronous calls on `Action<T>` methods. It basically just implements the pattern for when you want to execute the method and don't care about it's progress:

```
public static class ActionExtensions
{
    public static void AsyncInvoke<T>(this Action<T> action, T param) {
        action.BeginInvoke(param, AsyncActionCallback, action);
    }

    private static void AsyncActionCallback<T>(IAsyncResult asyncResult) {
        Action<T> action = (Action<T>)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        action.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it won't compile because of the extra `<T>` that makes the `AsyncActionCallback` generic and have a different signature than expected. 
The signature `void AsyncActionCallback(IAsyncResult)` is expected.

Does anyone know how to work around this or to accomlish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static void AsyncInvoke<T>(this Action<T> action, T param)
{
    action.BeginInvoke(param, asyncResult => 
    {
        Action<T> a = (Action<T>)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        a.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
    }, action);
}
```

Comment: That's one way  :) Good thinking.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for that blazing fast answer! It's interesting how lambdas enable something that was not possible before. I guess it's not just sugar after all!

Comment: Note that this approach may let any errors that occur during invocation get dropped on the floor. You might want to wrap the contents of the lambda inside a try { } catch { }.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncActionCallback<T>` ?

Disclaimer: not sure about the above, could be one of those 'limitations'.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am using that exact same signature in the code I posted. But again that would not compile because the compiler does not expect the type parameter <T>. Anyway, Darin's solution using a lamda instead of the delegate works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your function separated (not as lambda) what about something like this:

```
public static void AsyncInvoke<T>(Action<T> action, T param)
{
    action.BeginInvoke(param, new AsyncCallback(AsyncActionCallback<T>), action);
}
```